# facebook sdk 3.0 not working in android 4 and above

Tags: android, facebook

My app is working on android 2.2, I have just changed the facebook sdk to 3.0. But after that when I am going to login with facebook, it make facebook login window closed and it throws me out of app. It is only happenes in android 4.0 or above, but it still works for android 2.2, android 2.3.

Can anyone know the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK 3.0 changed a lot of things. Paste your login code here.